# Append a XML tag within an XML object

Tags: java

I'm trying to insert a tag inside an XML object.

Tried the SO answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567046/appending-new-tag-to-the-existing-xml-using-java) in a different way, but couldnt achieve it.

This is what my request XML looks like.

```
<Root>
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <Type>2345</Type>
    <Value>RootId</Value>
    <IdNum>1234-2345</IdNum>
</Root>
```

And I had to add a  tag to it.

```
<Root>
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <Type>2345</Type>
    <Value>RootId</Value>
    <IdNum>1234-2345</IdNum>
    <RefId>1234-2345</RefId>
</Root>
```

My code looks like below:

```
...  
Element rootEle = document.getElementsByTagName("Root").item(0); 
NodeList idNode = rootEle.getElementsByTagName("IdNum");
                           
Text refValue = document.createTextNode(rootEle.getElementsByTagName("IdNum").item(0).getTextContent());
Element refElement = document.createElement("RefId");
refElement.appendChild(refValue);
idNode.item(0).getParentNode().insertBefore(refElement,idNode.item(0));
```

Tried to print the IdNum like below and it is printing the expected result. But the additional tag alone is not getting appended.

```
rootEle.getElementsByTagName("IdNum").item(0).getTextContent()
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: try `idNode.item(0).getParentNode().insertBefore(refElement,null);`

Comment: Tried this Marc. Didnt work. Receiving the same XML.

Comment: serialized the document again, the element is there `<RefId>1234-2345</RefId>`

Comment: You're right Marc. The sample which I provided is just an example and your suggestion works just fine for it. But my original request starts with SOAP headers like `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <port:getAllContractsByPartyResponse xmlns:port="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/port">` for which your suggestion is not working. Does it have anything to do with that?

Comment: yes, you'll need to add xml namespaces to the new element