# Change inside value of XML specific tag

Tags: java, xml, xpath, methods, tags

Imagine this XML:

```
<DocumentElement>
  <PropsAndValues>
    <Name># CONFIGURATION_NODE # DO NOT DELETE THIS ROW #</Name>
    <Keywords>#</Keywords>
    <Tests>#</Tests>
    <Type>#</Type>
  </PropsAndValues>
  <PropsAndValues>
    <Name>PersonSuiteTC-1</Name>
    <Keywords/>
    <Tests>Definition:"Business Process":PersonSuiteTC-1</Tests>
    <Type>HIGH</Type>
  </PropsAndValues>
  <PropsAndValues>
    <Name>No Operation</Name>
    <Keywords/>
    <Tests/>
    <Type>TECH</Type>
  </PropsAndValues>
  <PropsAndValues>
    <Name>Start</Name>
    <Keywords>No Operation</Keywords>
    <Tests/>
    <Type>LOW</Type>
  </PropsAndValues>
  <PropsAndValues>
    <Name>Open Application</Name>
    <Keywords>No Operation</Keywords>
    <Tests/>
    <Type>LOW</Type>
  </PropsAndValues>
  <PropsAndValues>
    <Name>Go To Profile Finder</Name>
    <Keywords>No Operation</Keywords>
    <Tests/>
    <Type>LOW</Type>
  </PropsAndValues>
  <PropsAndValues>
    <Name>Search Person</Name>
    <Keywords>No Operation</Keywords>
    <Tests/>
    <Type>LOW</Type>
  </PropsAndValues>
  <PropsAndValues>
    <Name>End</Name>
    <Keywords>No Operation</Keywords>
    <Tests/>
    <Type>LOW</Type>
  </PropsAndValues>
  <PropsAndValues>
    <Name>PersonSuiteTC-1</Name>
    <Keywords>
    Start Open Application Go To Profile Finder Search Person End
    </Keywords>
    <Tests/>
    <Type>HIGH</Type>
  </PropsAndValues>
</DocumentElement>
```

I need to create a method with this header:

```
private static void addRelation(String kWName, String elemName) throws Exception {

}
```

that adds elemName to the tag `<Keywords>` of a Node that has `<Name>` tag value the kwName.

For example:

`addRelation("PersonSuiteTC-1", "Add this String to <Keywords> tag")`, should go to the node with the name "PersonSuiteTC-1" and add "Add this String to  tag" to the `<Keywords>` tag.

What's the easiest way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

**1 parse your XML .**

Use that for example:

```
String xml= your xml
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

**2 find your point of insertion.**

Use XPath, with something like that:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
expression="//Name[text()='PersonSuiteTC-1']";

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expression) ; 
NodeList nodes  = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

note that you have several nodes with this text

you can iterate:

for (int k = 0; k < nodes.getLength(); k++) {

```
  Node nodeSegment = nodes.item(k);
```

**3 insert your data:**

use *createElement(), createTextNode(), appendChild()*

see that: [How do I append a node to an existing XML file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445828/how-do-i-append-a-node-to-an-existing-xml-file-in-java)

**4 generate you xml back:**

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Result out = new StreamResult(new File("result.xml"));
Source in = new DOMSource(document);
transformer.transform(in, out);
```

Hope it helps !