# How to build a dynamic JNLP file?

Tags: java, jsp, web, jnlp

I am creating a `jnlp` file but I need to receive some URL parameters.

I have a method that captures the URL from a `jsp` file:

```
String getParameter (HttpServletRequest request, String param)
```

The problem is how to add parameters to the `jnlp` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="https://localhost:8443/java-web-start/test/" href="start.jnlp">

    <information>
        <title>TestApp</title>
        <vendor>Oracle</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <java version="1.5+"/>
        <jar href="start.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.Main"/>
</jnlp>
```

Here's the `index.jsp` file:

```
<%!
    String getParameter(HttpServletRequest request, String param) {
        String result = request.getParameter(param);
        return result.replace("&", "&amp;").replace("\"", "&quot;").replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;").replace("'","$#039;");
    }
%>

<%=getParameter(request, "requestURL")%>
```

I want this in my `jnlp` File and then Download and execute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="https://localhost:8443/java-web-start/test/" href="start.jnlp">

    <information>
        <title>TestApp</title>
        <vendor>Oracle</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <java version="1.5+"/>
        <jar href="start.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="com.Main">
        <argument><%= clientCount %></argument>
        <argument><%=getParameter(request, "requestURL")%></argument>
    </<application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Why don't you load you `jnlp` and append the `argument`s you want, treating the `jnlp` file as a simple XML file that it is? Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445828/how-do-i-append-a-node-to-an-existing-xml-file-in-java) example on how to append nodes on XML.

Comment: Thank you, now it works, I generate the File as simple XML.

Comment: If it's ok with you, I'm going to post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your `jnlp` and append the arguments you want, treating the `jnlp` file as a simple XML file that it is.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445828/how-do-i-append-a-node-to-an-existing-xml-file-in-java) example on how to append nodes on XML.